# Issue with implementing form field of a belongs_to model

Tags: yii

For model, UserStore with fields id, user_id, store_id, I have made a relation as follows:

```
'storeUserNames' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
```

where User model has the fields id, name.

I am loading the model for update as follows:

```
$model = UserStore::model()->with('storeUserNames')->find(array('condition' => 't.id=:id',
                'params' => array(':id'=>$id));
...
```

Now, the issue is with the display of user name in the form, which I coded as follows:

```
 <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'storeUserNames.name',array('maxlength'=>150)); ?>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Property "UserStore.storeUserNames.name" is not defined.
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model->storeUserNames,'name',array('maxlength'=>150)); ?>
```

That should work. Also remember that this creates a field called User[name] and not the UserStore[] how the other fields are.